# Windows PowerShell. Run program by PowerShell command

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to run the file `C:\Python34\python.exe` the command of `python3` and the file `C:\Python27\python.exe` the python command. How can I define this behavior it via PowerShell?

I usually add it to my `~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` strings like:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add files `~\bin\python.bat` and `~\bin\python3.bat` with contents `C:\Python27\python.exe` and `C:\Python34\python.exe`, and add to your `profile.ps1`

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Users\<your user>\bin"
```